# Excel VBA - Sum all accesses and users from different worksheets into new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following worksheets

**Users from XXX**

```
Users    Access
Foo      30
Bar      45
```

**Users from YYY**

```
Users    Access
Beef     90
Foo      85
```

**Sums of accesses**

```
Users    Access
```

If the users from the **XXX** table match with the ones in the **YYY** table then I want to append the User and the **sum** of accesses from both worksheets into the **Sums of accesses** one

So far I've come up with

```
Sub CalcularSoma()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, r_users_a As Range, r_acessos_a As Range, r_users_b As Range, r_acessos_b As Range
  Set sh1 = Worksheets("Users XXX")
  Set sh2 = Worksheets("Users YYY")
  Set sh3 = Worksheets("Sum of all")

  Set r_users_a = sh1.Range("A2")
  Set r_acess_a = sh1.Range("B2")

  Set r_users_b = sh2.Range("A2")
  Set r_acess_b = sh2.Range("B2")

End Sub
```

But I can't get my head around on how I would loop through each and then append

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `For each` loop to go to each cell for `USER XXX` and then another for `USER YYY` to finally paste when there are matches in the other table.

```
Sub CopyRows()
  Dim r_users_a As Range, r_acess_a As Range, r_users_b As Range, r_acess_b As Range, r_users_c As Range, r_acess_c As Range
  Dim count As Integer

  count = 0

  Set r_users_a = Range("D3:D5")
  Set r_acess_a = Range("E3:E5")

  Set r_users_b = Range("H3:H5")
  Set r_acess_b = Range("I3:I5")

  Set r_users_c = Range("P3:P5")
  Set r_acess_c = Range("Q3:Q5")

  For Each cell In r_users_a
    For Each cellB In r_users_b
        If cell.Value = cellB.Value Then
            Cells(r_users_c.Row + count, r_users_c.Column).Value = cell.Value
            Cells(r_users_c.Row + count, r_users_c.Column + 1).Value = Cells(cellB.Row, cellB.Column + 1).Value + Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Value
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cellB
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed the Cell range and that just prints a bunch of zeros

Comment: You changed it for both ranges ? Don't forget to add your sheet definitions too...

Comment: If you want me to help you, you must give out more information than this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dictionary Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dictionary-object) to save each unique item, and update the value.

```
Sub CalcularSoma()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, r_users_a As Range, r_acessos_a As Range, r_users_b As Range, r_acessos_b As Range
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Users XXX")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Users YYY")
Set sh3 = Worksheets("Sum of all")


Set r_users_a = sh1.Range("A2:A" & sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Range("A:A").Rows(sh1.Range("A:A").Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Row)
Set r_acess_a = sh1.Range("B2")


Set r_users_b = sh2.Range("A2:A" & sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Range("A:A").Rows(sh2.Range("A:A").Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Row)
Set r_acess_b = sh2.Range("B2")

'We use the Dictionary
Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'Make key non case sensitive (the dictionary must be empty).


Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In r_users_a
    If Dict.Exists(Rng.Value) Then
        'we update value
        Dict(Rng.Value) = Dict(Rng.Value) + Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Else
        'we add it
        Dict.Add (Rng.Value), Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next Rng

For Each Rng In r_users_b
    If Dict.Exists(Rng.Value) Then
        'we update value
        Dict(Rng.Value) = Dict(Rng.Value) + Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Else
        'we add it
        Dict.Add (Rng.Value), Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next Rng

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To Dict.Count - 1 Step 1
   Debug.Print Dict.Keys(i), Dict.Items(i)
Next i

Dict.RemoveAll

Set Dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

After executing this, I get:

```
Foo            115 
Bar            45 
Beef           90
```